# Get Available Balance from transaction table using MYSQL

Tags: mysql

[image]

I tried to get available balance of specific account number using SQL QUERY my code is below:

select sum(amount) as Cr form transaction where credit=1 and account_no=2549
Union
select sum(amount) as Dr form transaction where debit=1 and account_no=2549

Difference Cr-Dr

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `case` to get sum for credit and debit in single query as

```
select sum(case when credit=1 then amount else 0 end) as Cr ,
sum(case when debit=1 then amount else 0 end) Dr,
sum(case when credit=1 then amount else 0 end) - sum(case when debit=1 then amount else 0 end) as available_balance
from `transaction` 
where account_no=2549
```

Answer (score 0):

The below query should work for you to get available balance.

```
select sum(amt) from 
(select 
case 
    when credit=1 then amount
    when debit=1 then -amount
    else 0 
end as amt
from transaction 
where account_no = 5294)t;
```